# How to run a BASH script in response to a network event?

Tags: macos, networking, bash

I've got a little BASH script I'd like to run on a few Mac's (A mix of 10.8.5 and 10.9.4). I'd like to trigger the script whenever my mac attempts to connect to another one through a particular TCP port. The IP addresses of both of the computers are known, and I can see the traffic (connection on port 6472) when I watch via nettop or console.

What I haven't been able to find - and perhaps I'm not searching correctly - is a tool that will run in the background and watch for that connection request, then run an executable when it occurs. I suppose I could cook one up, but this seems like a problem that others have already solved. Any direction toward an existing solution would be most welcome.

Thanks! Mike

Answer (score 0):

How about running something like this in the background, using [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) with the right filter and firing up your script each time it matches ?

```
tcpdump -l -i eth0 'dst host other_host and dst port 6472 and tcp[tcpflags] = tcp-syn' 2>/dev/null | while read f ; do your_script; done
```

replace `eth0` with your network interface, `other_host` with the other machine's IP address

If you don't want a terminal window lying around you can make this a bash script and run it inside a [screen](http://aperiodic.net/screen/start) session.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, and possibly simpler solution to @ultrasawblade solution might be to run [knockd](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock/). - It appears there is a version of it available for Mac.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will do exactly what I need with a minimum of fuss. It'll be a few days before I can try it out, but I appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most versatile and customised approach to finish your quest is to peruse `dtrace`.

Either use a generic socket or tcp provider and run the script in destructive mode to call `system()` from the kernel or use Function Boundary Tracing (FBT) as your provider. The latter will make your script dependent on the OSX version.

Toying around a bit, I came up with something that should give you enough fodder for your final solution using a socket provider (so it should work on both of your MacOSX machines):

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option quiet
#pragma D option switchrate=10hz
#pragma D option destructive 

/* AF_INET{6} are unknown to dtrace, so replace with numbers */
inline int af_inet  =  2; /* AF_INET  */
inline int af_inet6 = 30; /* AF_INET6 */
inline const string procname = "nc";

dtrace:::BEGIN
{
    /* Add translations as desired from /usr/include/sys/errno.h */
    err[0]            = "Success";
    err[EINTR]        = "Interrupted syscall";
    err[EIO]          = "I/O error";
    err[EACCES]       = "Permission denied";
    err[ENETDOWN]     = "Network is down";
    err[ENETUNREACH]  = "Network unreachable";
    err[ECONNRESET]   = "Connection reset";
    err[ECONNREFUSED] = "Connection refused";
    err[ETIMEDOUT]    = "Timed out";
    err[EHOSTDOWN]    = "Host down";
    err[EHOSTUNREACH] = "No route to host";
    err[EINPROGRESS]  = "In progress";
    err[EADDRNOTAVAIL] = "Can't assign requested address";

    printf("%-6s %-20s %-8s %-21s %-21s %-8s %s\n", 
        "PID", "PROCNAME", "FAMILY", "S_ADDR:S_PORT", "D_ADDR:D_PORT", 
        "LAT(us)", "RESULT");
}

/*  MacOSX connectx() syscall:

    connectx(arg0:int s, arg1:struct sockaddr *src, arg2:socklen_t srclen, 
                         arg3:struct sockaddr *dsts, arg4:socklen_t dstlen, 
                         arg5:uint32_t ifscope, arg6: associd_t aid, 
                         arg7:connid_t *cid);
*/

syscall::connectx:entry
{
    this->s = (struct sockaddr_in *) copyin(arg3, sizeof(struct sockaddr)); 
    this->f = this->s->sin_family;
} 

syscall::connectx:entry 
/ this->f == af_inet && execname == procname / 
{ 
    this->s = (struct sockaddr_in *) copyin(arg1, sizeof(struct sockaddr)); 
    self->address = inet_ntop(this->f, (void *) &this->s->sin_addr);
    self->port = ntohs(this->s->sin_port);
    self->s_addr = strjoin(strjoin(self->address, ":"), lltostr(self->port));

    this->d = (struct sockaddr_in *) copyin(arg3, sizeof(struct sockaddr)); 
    self->address = inet_ntop(this->f, (void *) &this->d->sin_addr);
    self->port = ntohs(this->d->sin_port);  
    self->d_addr = strjoin(strjoin(self->address, ":"), lltostr(self->port));

    self->ts = timestamp; 
}

syscall::connectx:entry
/ this->f == af_inet6 && execname == procname /
{
    this->s6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) copyin(arg1, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    self->port = ntohs(this->s6->sin6_port);
    self->address = inet_ntop(this->f, (void *) &this->s6->sin6_addr);
    self->s_addr = strjoin(strjoin(self->address, ":"), lltostr(self->port));

    this->d6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) copyin(arg3, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    self->port = ntohs(this->d6->sin6_port);
    self->address = inet_ntop(this->f, (void *) &this->d6->sin6_addr);
    self->d_addr = strjoin(strjoin(self->address, ":"), lltostr(self->port));

    self->ts = timestamp;
}

syscall::connectx:return 
/ self->ts / 
{ 
    this->delta = (timestamp - self->ts) / 1000; 
    this->errstr = err[errno] != NULL ? err[errno] : lltostr(errno);

    /* Basically anything can be called here */
    system("date");
    printf("%-6d %-20s %-8d %-21s %-21s %-8d %s\n", 
        pid, execname, this->f, self->s_addr, self->d_addr,
        this->delta, this->errstr); 

    self->family = 0; 
    self->ts = 0; 
}
```

Save it to a file (let's say `./socket_connect_mac_simple.d`) and then call the code as follows:

```
$ sudo ./socket_connect_mac_simple.d
```

Open another terminal and fire up `nc` as a server:

```
$ nc -4 -k -l 127.0.0.1 6472 > /dev/null
```

And in yet another terminal, connect to it:

```
$ while :; do nc -4 -s 192.168.0.19 127.0.0.1 6472 < /usr/bin/true; sleep 0.5; done
```

Your output should look something along the lines of this:

```
$ sudo ./socket_connect_mac_simple.d
PID    PROCNAME         FAMILY   S_ADDR:S_PORT         D_ADDR:D_PORT         LAT(us)  RESULT
45823  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        240      Success
45825  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        234      Success
45827  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        236      Success
45829  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        240      Success
45831  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        241      Success
45833  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        238      Success
45835  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        234      Success
45837  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        241      Success
45839  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        236      Success
45841  nc               2        192.168.0.19:0        127.0.0.1:6472        237      Success
```

Obviously, you will be replacing `nc` with your daemon listing on port 6472 and you will also have to call your bash script where I put the `system("date")` code fragment. Other than that, it should pretty much just work as you described it.

Make sure that you read the fine documentation about the destructive mode dtrace call `system()`: [Destructive Mode Calls inside DTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-actsub-4/index.html)